# Django - access parameters of the previous request

Tags: django

**The problem:**

I am working on a webapp that has a 'StudentListView' that should have the following features:

1. Display a list of students
2. Have a searchbox above that allows the user to filter / search this list (Submitting 'Peter' should return all students with 'Peter' in their name)
3. An 'export' button should allow the user to export this (possibly filtered!) list to a `.csv` file

I've implemented the code below to allow the user to filter the list, which works as intended. I've also created an `export_students` function that creates an `.csv` file of all students in the supplied queryset. This function also works as intended.

However, when exporting a filtered list the program does not behave as the user expects.  The user will first filter the list by providing search parameters, which will trigger an request and refresh the page. The user than presses the 'export' button, but since he did not re-submit the search parameters (why would he, the list he sees is already filtered) none are provided in the request and thus the csv file contain all students in the database, instead of the filtered selection he expects.

**Possible solution**

This problem would be solved if I could somehow store the search parameters of the request, and have them retrieved if the following `request.GET` contains the `exportstudents` keyword. But I am not sure how I could accomplish this. The closest I got was by using javascript to append the search params to the value of the `Export` button. But this meant that `request.GET['exportstudents']` had the entire search query as its value (I removed most of the search/filter options in my code examples for simplicity, but these parameter strings can get really long)

I could of course parse the results with a complicated regex but seems like a very convoluted solution for a problem that probably has a much easier solution.

**The code**

Again, I removed most of the filter parameters for simplicity, but the code below should give an good indication of how my view functions.

The HTML appends keywords to the requests `.GET` parameter, which, if present, are either used to filter the queryset or trigger the `export_students` function.

```
<form method="get">
  <input name="search_query" type="text" class="form-control"
     value="{% if request.GET.q %}{{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}"
     placeholder="Find student"
  />
  <button type="submit">Filter Students</button></span>
</form>

<form id='exportform' class="col-md-5 " method="get" action="">
   <div class="input-group">
     <button id='export' name="exportstudents" value="true">Export Students</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

```
class StudentListView(generic.ListView)

    def get_queryset(self):
        field = self.request.GET.get('field', 'last_name')
        qs = Student.objects.all()
        search_query = self.request.GET.get('search_query', None)
        if search_query:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(first_name__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(last_name__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(email_parents__icontains=search_query)
            )
        return qs
```

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'exportstudents' in self.request.GET:
            qs = self.get_queryset()
            file = export_students(qs)
            content = 'attachment; filename="{}_{}.csv"'.format(
                u'Student_export',
                timezone.now().strftime('%d-%m_%H:%M')
            )
            response = StreamingHttpResponse(
                file, content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return super(UserListView, self).get(request, *args, 
            **kwargs)
```

The functionality that this view seeks to provide are commonplace on many websites, so obviously a solution is possible. But I am currently at a loss on how to allow users to export filtered lists when those filters have been applied to the previous queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export students is also a form. So you could add the parameter there as a hidden field - now your existing view code will just work.

```html
<form id='exportform' class="col-md-5 " method="get" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="search_query" value="{{ request.GET.search_query }}"
   <div class="input-group">
     <button id='export' name="exportstudents" value="true">Export Students</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, just use a single form with two buttons:

```
<form method="get">
  <input name="search_query" type="text" class="form-control"
     value="{% if request.GET.q %}{{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}"
     placeholder="Find student"
  />
  <button type="submit">Filter Students</button></span>

   <div class="input-group">
     <button id='export' name="exportstudents" value="true">Export Students</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Again, this will just work (although I suspect you meant `request.GET.search_query` there too).

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 2):

You may also be able to get access to the previous request's GET using the `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` header on the request. But it is possible that some browsers could be configured not to send the referer.